# Unity Box Collider 2D Пересечение

Tags: unity3d, 2d

Как отловить пересечение игроком объекта, не задевание, а именно пересечение? Box Collider 2D

Comment: `OnTriggerEnter2D`?

Comment: OnTriggerEnter2D срабатывает даже, если просто задел границу объекта. Нужно именно, если пересек/покинул границу объекта.

Comment: Ну вообще "задел границу объекта" - это и есть "пересечение" объектов. Приведите пример в виде изображения, со слов я не понимаю, чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: [Вот что я имею в виду](https://ibb.co/S6HkSdK)

Comment: Player включает в себя Rigidbody 2D & Box Collider 2D. Лестница - Box Collider 2D. Отлов события нужен, чтобы сменить анимацию из состояния "на лестнице поднимаемся/остановились" к состоянию "стоим на платформе".

Comment: В принципе есть вариант над "лестницей" поместить пустой объект, невидимый Box Collider 2D. И если вошел в его границы, то будет считаться, что игрок над лестницей.

Comment: Все еще не вижу проблемы поставить на лестницу триггер и через `OnTriggerExit2D()` отлавливать, когда персонаж покинет ее область.